# Unable to perform inference on kaggle using model trained on colab :DecodeError: Error parsing message

Tags: tensorflow, protocol-buffers, google-colaboratory, kaggle, inference

I trained an object detection model on colab and saved the frozen_inference graph.pb and other files.I'm able to perform inference using the frozen graph on colab but not on kaggle(it's important to submit the submission as a notebook).
when I try to load the graph:

```
<ipython-input-70-5c59468315ee> in gwc_test(path, img)
     63       with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
     64           serialized_graph = fid.read()
---> 65           od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
     66           tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
     67 

DecodeError: Error parsing message
```

I can give more information if someone knows how I can work it out.